# Issue in initWithBase64EncodedString in NSData+Base64.m

Tags: ios, base64

Just noticed this and wanted to mention it.  If anyone has seen this issue and / or where it is kept to get it fixed it would be appreciated...

The line in the routine

```
outbuf [2] = ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x03 ) << 6 ) | ( inbuf[3] & 0x3F );
```

Has a problem since the inbuf has only 3 indexes.  I have not detailed the code out yet, may have to in the near future.  Just seeing if this has been fixed but all versions of the code that I have seen has this issue.

```
unsigned char inbuf[3], outbuf[4];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it inbuf[4]

It doesn't crash cause you are on a 32 bit system, so it will give you an int and split from there.

Comment: Well, I have not have time to look at the alg, is this correct for the alg?  I agree on the 32 / 64 bit system will probably be ok, but need to see if this is correct for the alg.  I'll try and take some time and prove to myself that this would be ok.

Comment: You read four bytes into that array. Since the item will become a four byte int, it hasn't produced bad results and hasn't indexed out of range because a whole int is given for that size. 

To remove the warning simply adjust the inbuf to inbuf[4] so there's a one to one match on the outbuf. Hope this helps!